# Remove id and .html in url with htaccess redirection

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this URL:

```
http://[DOMAIN]/[category]/27466-some-article-is-here.html
```

Which should redirect to this URL:

```
http://[DOMAIN]/[category]/some-article-is-here
```

My effort till now

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*example\.com\/.+)(?:\/[\d]{5})\-(.*)$ $1/$2
```

I try to write, but don't know how to finish it

Comment: Try `^(.*)/\d{5}-([^/]*?)(?:\.[^/.]+)?$` pattern

Comment: FYI, `RedirectMatch` is not part of mod_rewrite, so turning on the rewrite engine is completely superfluous here.

Answer (score 1):

The regex applies only to the URL path, not to the host.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/.+)(?:\/[\d]{5})\-(.*)$ $1/$2
```

And to remove the `.html`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/.+)(?:\/[\d]{5})\-(.*)\.html$ $1/$2
```

And it can be simplified to:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)/\d{5}-(.*)\.html$ $1/$2
```

(tested with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: As noted in the comments above, `RewriteEngine` (mod_rewrite) is not required here. `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive.